# How to compile/build open source projects on Windows?

Tags: c++, dll, makefile, compilation, cross-compiling

I need to use a number of open source projects in my code (C++) and so I need them compiled as DLLs. However, most of these projects don't include redistributable binaries, so I have to compile everything myself. Usually the instructions are written for Linux and so the output ends up being either a .so file or a .a file. But that won't work because I need a DLL and a .lib file. I want my program compatible with Windows because most users are Windows users.

I have run into this situation so frequently that I am wondering if there is a standard procedure to deal with this that makes it quick and easy. Most of these projects are supposed to be installed by running "configure" and then "make", and I do understand how to do exactly that on Linux, but any solutions I've found using Windows seem to involve something like MSYS, MinGW, Cygwin, or something else which not only complicates things but doesn't even work half the time, with cryptic error messages that I can't actually resolve. I've had to download a number of libraries using the package managers on those platforms just to get it to compile, and then when I do produce a DLL an run it on Windows it half the time it doesn't work and I have no way of actually dealing with the problem.

Is there a simple solution to this common issue?

Comment: In short: no.  Windows is sufficiently different, in basically every way, from POSIX systems like GNU/Linux or MacOS that it's a huge amount of effort for people to create projects that are portable between them.  Most open source projects don't have the resources to do it.  The difference in build systems is just the tip of the iceberg, but it's probably the most visible to people who just want to compile things.  The entire idea behind cygwin is to provide a POSIX environment on Windows, but it does mean that the resulting software needs a cygwin DLL (IIUC).

Comment: If the libraries aren't available on package managers like Conan or vcpkg then you'll just have to put up with the pain. Of course you're probably quite welcome to submit Windows patches to those projects to improve things

Comment: What about sharing some of the projects, and the final goal?

Comment: can give me a link to the opensource project?

Comment: @CristiFati Examples: [secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1), [OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl), [libscrypt](https://github.com/technion/libscrypt) I ditched OpenSSL and libscrypt for [Crypto++](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp) which I got from vcpkg. But when it's not in conan or vcpkg (like secp256k1) it's a massive pain to build these due to either nonexistent or poor instructions. Wasted literally days trying and I had to cheat by downloading the DLL from some random website. Still struggling to build a working secp256k1 DLL on Windows on my own.

Comment: @kenash0625 For instance with secp256k1, only recently the devs added [Windows DLL support](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/commit/61ae37c61261a43c1199d112a79a7ad64442f36d) and even when you build it only produces a DLL not a .lib so I needed to use a [bash script](https://github.com/Mattiwatti/dumplib) to create the .lib. I also got different errors when linking, one when you link x64 to an x86 program, another saying it needed MSYS2.0-dll to run. And now I realized the .lib doesn't even have all the functions from the include files. Hours of wasted time that should be much easier.

Comment: It also seems like [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70444052/how-to-build-secp256k1-on-windows) had trouble building that particular project today but got a very negative response. Though I didn't want this to be an issue specific to any repo, I've had trouble building other projects. I could talk about these random issues I've had all day. I would just encourage open source developers to spend more time writing helpful documentation for others to easily and quickly use their software instead of refactoring random parts of code.

Comment: Lastly @MadScientist I should have mentioned I've used other libraries like SDL2 or SFML and those come pre-built as DLLs for Windows. I guess those are the exception rather than the rule? It's very easy for a game developer to just grab SDL2 or SFML and make a game rather than jump through the hoops of trying to build their own tools. So I get your point and I appreciate the honesty but it's kind of sad if that's true.

Comment: You might find some *pkg*s on https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries. But using some tools like the ones you mentioned (*MinGW*, *MSYS*) which emulate *Posix* on *Win* is very popular and there are tons of software built that way. I'm guessing the errors you get, you'd get anyway because it's not because of the tool but because of something wrong in your environment.

Comment: If what's true?  That it's a lot of work to create libraries that are portable between Windows and POSIX?  Yes, that's definitely unfortunate.  Or that many free software projects don't have the resources to do it?  That's also too bad.  The only way for it to get better is for people who want Windows support to get involved and help out by adding that support to free software projects they would like to be portable.